# How to make mailto link in gwt?

Tags: gwt

How to make mailto link in gwt using Label, Hyperlink or anyother Widget and add that widget in DisclosurePanel. Any Idea please?

Answer (score 5):

```java
disclosurePanel.setContent(
    new Anchor("Contact us", "mailto:contact@example.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will perhaps want to open the mailto in abither browser tab :

```
disclosurePanel.setContent(
    new Anchor("Contact us", "mailto:contact@example.com"), "_blank");
```